# Enable GZIP for CSS and JS files on NGINX server for Magento

Tags: magento, nginx, gzip

I need to enable gzip compression on nginx server. As I have  observed from firfox firebug NET tools, I have found that html file are gzip compressed. But Not the javascript files and CSS files.

I have already check **Mime.types** and nginx configuration file **/etc/nginx/ngnix.conf** and not found any issue.
still not able to see the css and javascript Gzip Compression.
My NGINX.conf entries are as below

```
gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
```

Comment: If you choose the ever-popular [Fooman Speedster](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/fooman-speedster.html) then JS and CSS are gzipped anyway.

Comment: @clockworkgeek..Thanks !!! But I want to configure nginx, so the CSS and JS Files can be gzip compressed.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

This is an working config that I currently use in production.

http://pastie.org/10870547

```
gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types
    text/plain
    text/css
    text/js
    text/xml
    text/javascript
    application/javascript
    application/json
    application/xml
    application/rss+xml
    image/svg+xml;
```

This config was tested via tools.pingdom.com.

Comment: Thanks For Reply. .I don't know .. what is the reason but this has not work for me..!! Can you explain step by step process to debug the problem or what should be the proper steps for enabling gzip compression for css and JS files.. The most surprising thing is Gzip is working for html content ie text/html MIME Types but not for CSS and JS. One more thing is that Varnish cache is also enabled on the server and Server OS is ubuntu..!!

Comment: Is your head and header hole-punched with esi tags?  If they are, they would be served from Varnish.

Comment: Should add svg into the answer tbh

Comment: Thanks! needed to remove application/x-javascript all working fine!

Comment: does this support default [gzip_types](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html#gzip_types) `text/html` value?

Comment: Please note, `gzip_types` enables gzipping of responses for the specified MIME types in *addition* to “text/html”.

Answer (score 42):

You can find example configuration from the [html5 boilerplate](https://github.com/darktable/html5-boilerplate-server-configs/blob/master/nginx.conf) code.

```
  # Enable Gzip
  gzip  on;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_comp_level 2;
  gzip_min_length 1100;
  gzip_buffers     4 8k;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_types
    # text/html is always compressed by HttpGzipModule
    text/css
    text/javascript
    text/xml
    text/plain
    text/x-component
    application/javascript
    application/json
    application/xml
    application/rss+xml
    font/truetype
    font/opentype
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    image/svg+xml;

  gzip_static on;

  gzip_proxied        expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_disable        "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_vary           on;
```

Comment: thanks for `text/html is always compressed by HttpGzipModule`

Answer (score 8):

If some of your files are compressed and some are not, then your gzip is working but you might have missed definition in **gzip_types**. For example, javascript files may return in headers any of following type:

- application/javascript
- application/x-javascript
- text/javascript

To compress all javascript files, all three definitions should be included in gzip_types.

You need to check in **response headers** what content-type is returned for such an uncompressed file and then make sure it is also defined in gzip_types.

Comment: This is important! All three definitions should be included in gzip_types....This answer made my gtmetrix score jump from 74% to 92%

Comment: Thanks. Works. Will check the response header for one of my files. It looks like it doesn't get compressed.

Comment: My browser, Firefox 59.0b5, request javascript file as type: `application/javascript`, i miss this in `gzip_types`, caused not work, after add this type, it worked now!

Answer (score 3):

Are your gzip entries within the nginx configuration "scope" that js,css,etc. assets are being served? I ask because if you're using some sort of a framework, sometimes there are different location {...} blocks that handle html requests vs assets.

Also when you're testing in a browser, make sure you do a hard refresh to force the server to give you a "fresh copy" of whatever you're looking at.

Finally, you can use gzip_types * to allow anything to be gzipped. Perhaps someone else can chime in if this is a good practice or not.

Comment: Can you give some examples?

Comment: eg: location ~* .*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css|txt|wsdl|html) {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

Comment: Typically gzip_types * wouldn't be advisable. It may try to compress already compressed resources, or difficult to compress resources (like some images).This probably won't result in a significant space saving. Thus, it acts as a penalty simply wasting time while it gzips the resource. `gzip_min_length 1100;` directive also attempts to find this balance.

Answer (score 1):

To compress SVG, this line is correct:

```
image/svg+xml svg svgz;
```