# Enable content-encoding: gzip for production build in angular(7) web app?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5, angular7, angular8

When I generated the angular(7) production build with **ng build --prod** then generated main chunk size is 522 KB so I think is it is very large as I have very small application.
So my question is how to generate build with **content-encoding: gzip**? or Is there any other angular compression library I need to use?

See the below snapshot for more details.

**content-encoding: gzip example**

[image]

**Generated production build snapshot**

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to enable compression in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44758755/how-to-enable-compression-in-angular)

Comment: You can use any gzip compression library (or just the gzip command-line utility) to pre-compress the file. But you'll have to configure your server to serve the pre-gzipped file with the correct headers instead of the requested JS file. And servers are usually able to gzip responses all by themselves. So, read the documentation of your web server to know how to configure gzip compression.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the reply. Can you please suggest gzip compression library?

Comment: No. But as I said, there should be no need to pre-compress JS files. Just configure your web server to do it for you. And if you just want to check what size will a file be once compressed, just use `gzip file`.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks. I will try this.